# Meaning of a snippet

Tags: meaning

> "But because the idea of private property has been permitted to
>   override with its selfishness, the common good of humanity it, does
>   not follow that there are no limits within that idea, for what can
>   function for the general convenience and advantage."

Can anyone please explain the meaning of the above snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very badly written sentence. The grammar and punctuation are pretty poor.

I don't want to change the words and alter the meaning but I would say it ought to have been punctuated this way:

> "But, because the idea of private property has been permitted to override with its selfishness the common good of humanity, it does not follow that there are no limits within that idea for what can function for the general convenience and advantage."

This is how I understand it:

> ..because the idea of private property has been permitted to override with its selfishness the common good of humanity..

This is speaking about "private property" as an "idea", or a *concept*. I understand this to be the concept that property, or land *can* be owned. It suggests this idea has "overridden" any other idea, presumably the idea that nobody should own land.

It suggests that the concept of owning property is "selfish" and is contrary to "the common good of humanity".

> ...it does not follow that there are no limits within that idea for what can function for the general convenience and advantage.

This is saying that the concept of land ownership is "limited" and ultimately does not work for the greater number of people.

This is highly politically charged. It is in-line with the left-wing view of social equality and egalitarianism. Overall the message seems to be that the writer believes that land should **not** be owned by a few rich people; that presumably the entire planet belongs to all of humanity; and that available land resources should be used for the "convenience and advantage" of all.